# Is the potentiostat resistor wrong in this PDF?

Tags: potentiostat

I was reading this [potentiostat paper](http://eprints.gla.ac.uk/217958/7/217958.pdf): (which was found [here](http://eprints.gla.ac.uk/217955/))

[image: pot circuit]

I was wondering how this I/V current to voltage converter works to the right.  Correct me if I am wrong here.

I am pretty sure it goes like this:

Iwe flows in or out from the virtual GND of the C op-amp, but since no current flow there, it goes from the Rm (28.8MΩ), and creates a voltage difference there, which you can measure at Vout.

I wanted to confirm this so from the Table II, lets take the 26.6uA case:

[image: table 2]

The voltage across R8:

V=I*R => [image: latex]

766V is way larger from the 5V Op amp input.

Even if one looks at the graphs, lets take the 3*10^-5[A]:

[image: Graph]

[image: latex]

Again, a really large value.

I am starting to think that the values I find are in millivolts, or the author of the article used a smaller resistor and forgot to change its value on the PDF.

Comment: I will bet those currents are nA.

Comment: I cound not agree more, but it says **current(A)**  and **x10^-5**

Comment: Then that seems to leave the resistor being 28.8 k, so the schematic has an error. Given that the paper was published last year, maybe contact the corresponding author.

Comment: Will the horror of units in square brackets ever end?

Comment: In my shitty university, they taught me that the units are placed in brackets. I found this very smart since you can distinguish them from variables. And yes I have seen people hating them. Why is it so?

Comment: Here is the long form on correct usage:  https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/sp811.pdf   pages v and vi are an excellent summary.  Here is another one, starting on document page 130:  https://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si_brochure_8_en.pdf

Comment: In short [*] means"units of *" and can, of course, be used, but in the right way. [Ic]=A is correct and means the the quantity Ic is measured in amperes.Ic [A] is  nonsense instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resistor value was wrong after all. A resistor of lower value was needed to output something else rather than its maximum/minimum voltage.

With this larger resistor, the output was either +2.5V (maximum input voltage of the op amp) or -2.5V (the lower input voltage of the op amp.)